# Ignore multiple files with Chokidar

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Is there any way to ignore multiple files or directories when watching directory with Chokidar?

My code:

```
var ignoredFiles = ['c:/test/file1.txt', 'c:/test/file2.txt'];
//var ignoredFiles = 'c:/test/file1.txt';

var watchOptions: WatchOptions = <WatchOptions>{
            ignored: ignoredFiles,
            persistent: true,
            ignoreInitial: false,
            awaitWriteFinish: false,
            ignorePermissionErrors: false
        };
this.watcher = chokidar.watch('c:/test', watchOptions);
```

If I try to set ignored option to array of strings, it doesn't work. Moreover, even if I try to set it to string, it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions about a simple way of doing that? From Chokidar docs:

> ignored: (anymatch-compatible definition) Defines files/paths to be
>   ignored. The whole relative or absolute path is tested, not just
>   filename. If a function with two arguments is provided, it gets called
>   twice per path - once with a single argument (the path), second time
>   with two arguments (the path and the fs.Stats object of that path).

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with a regular expression? For example, ignored : /file[1-2]\.txt/

Comment: have you found a solution? I tried using regex myself too and no luck

Answer (score 1):

Various options for ignored

```
var ignoredFiles = ['c:/test/file1.txt', 'c:/test/file2.txt'];

var watchOptions = {
        ignored: ignoredFiles,
        persistent: true,
        ignoreInitial: false,
        awaitWriteFinish: false,
        ignorePermissionErrors: false
    };
this.watcher = chokidar.watch('c:/test', watchOptions);
```

or else

```
ignored: /file/, // ignores files and dirs which contain "file" in the name
```

You can also use regular expressions

```
ignored: /file[1-2]\.txt/, // ignores files matching this regex
```